# In HighChart (Scattar ) while adding dynamic data, existing data geting removed randomly

Tags: highcharts

While adding data dynamically to a scatter chart using Highchart, is there a way to prevent already rendered data point from disappearing randomly? I would prefer only data points that go outside the current x-axis limit to disappear.

`look at my code here`   [myfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zpDPd/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if point exists in series / data in your random() function.

http://jsfiddle.net/zpDPd/1/

```
var series = chart.series;
```

Then you should iterate for each series and each point and check if point is.